# Blinking or glowing button in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

I'm wondering how to create blinking or glowing "Alarm!" button/image.. For image -> one normal jpg, and one gif? Any easier solutions?

Comment: Please mention when you do you wan the button to be glowing - always or on an event like MouseHover

Comment: When Alarm is detected.. for example, received alarm message from rs232..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might this useful - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/VistaButton.aspx

Easy way is to create two image files , one with the glow, another without it . When the app receives the alarm change the button image .

Comment: Hmm, those aren't "Vista Style buttons". Vista-style buttons *actually* look like the one shown in my answer. But yes, you could custom drawn your own button if you wanted your app to look like it was designed by a 13-year-old kid that just pirated a copy of Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

The buttons in Windows Vista and Windows 7 already glow and throb by default when the user mouses over them, and/or when one is set as the default button for a form. The effect looks like this:

[image: Sample button]

If you're not getting this effect already, make sure that the [`FlatStyle`property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle.aspx) of your button control is set to "System".

Comment: Yummy, delicious, glowing, throbbing buttons! *ahem* and the like!

Comment: I want a button that does a dance number and then makes the tea.  How to do that?

Comment: Of course! Ordered and on it's way. Apparently it will unpack itself into the most photogenic place available in my house upon arrival and then recycle it's 'designed in california, made in china' packaging for me. Why have I waited so long.